# How to configure One Dark Material - Theme sublimetext 3

Tags: themes, sublimetext3

I want to set One Dark Material - Theme on sublimetext 3, I followed the instructions but can not get it to work.

While the parameters are my settings file?
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/One%20Dark%20Material%20-%20Theme
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"theme"` setting is correct. If you're trying to configure the color scheme that is included with the theme, simply select **`Sublime Text → Color Scheme → One Dark Material - Theme → schemes → OneDark`** and your preferences will be updated with the correct path automatically.